# Can I use TSQL to operate on normal os files? Such as create a .bat file and write some query result into that file?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

Can I use **TSQL** to operate on normal operating system files? Such as create a **.bat** file at **c:\test** and write some query result into that batch file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general tips on reading/writing files, you can check out [this](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/reading-and-writing-files-in-sql-server-using-t-sql/) link.

You can also use `SQLCMD`, like this (input.sql would be your input sql, Results.txt would be your output):

```
SQLCMD -i Input.sql -o C:\Results.txt -e
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes use [SQLCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175786(SQL.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use xp_cmdshell:

> **xp_cmdshell**
> Executes a given command string as an
> operating-system command shell and
> returns any output as rows of text.
> Grants nonadministrative users
> permissions to execute xp_cmdshell.

[link to: xp_cmdshell - msdn reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260689%28SQL.80%29.aspx)